# Animated canvas with dynamic sections

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, canvas

I am trying to implement the same idea as this: http://jsfiddle.net/oskar/Aapn8/ however I am trying to use sections of different sizes so rather than

```
var draw = function(current) {
    ctx.putImageData(imd, 0, 0);
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(120, 120, 70, -(quart), ((circ) * current) - quart, false);
    ctx.stroke();
}
```

as the draw function i am using:

```
var draw = function(current) {
     for (i = 0 ; i < degrees.length ; i++) {
        color = colors[i];
        ctx.fillStyle = colors[i];
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(cx,cy);
        ctx.arc(cx,cy,radius,start,start+toRad(degrees[i]));
        ctx.lineTo(cx,cy);
        ctx.closePath();
        ctx.fill();
        start += toRad(degrees[i]);
     }
}
```

But it doesn't work (https://jsfiddle.net/py6t8yj0/5/) but does draw the circle as desired.

I don't need the 'range' selector however I would like the bouncing effect once the circle reaches the end.

If anyone could be of help that'd be great :D.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

looks like you don't have Mootools included in that fiddle.  I am getting an error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: Fx is not defined
```

If you click the Javascript settings button, you can add a Mootools dependency.  Here's the jsfiddle updated with that dependency: https://jsfiddle.net/py6t8yj0/1/

Comment: I think I didn't update it when I added it, sorry. It draw the full circle but not the animated style in the first fiddle. I have updated my original now